# I cannot read the content of a .txt file in c# VS form applicaiton

Tags: c#, sockets

While im trying to read the txt file, it gets the full path correctly, but cannot read the content. I' ve tried other reading functions such as file.ReadAllText(path) etc. How to fix this?

```
try
        {
            string fileName = @"database.txt";
            string path = Path.GetFullPath(fileName); // fullpath of the txt gile
            clientlogs.AppendText(path+"\n"); // checking its correct or not.
            if (File.ReadAllLines(path) == null) // reading the content of the txt file to check whether the file is empty or not
            {
                clientlogs.AppendText( "file empty\n");
            }
            else
            {
                var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
                clientlogs.AppendText(lines + "\n");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            clientlogs.AppendText("Could not read the file!\n");
        }
```

screenshot of the output is below.

[image]

Comment: What's the error message? Try `catch (Exception e) { clientLogs.AppendText($"Could not read the file: {e.Message}\n");`

Comment: Are you trying to read a file from a remote computer via a local path? That won't fly. Looks like you want a OneDrive-Share Link (or whatever it's called in OD) instead ?

Comment: The system cannot find the file specified. However that file exists.

Comment: Dear fildor, the database txt file stores the information about the clients such as name, surname, username. When someone tries to create account, i need to check whether the username exists or not in the database.txt file. Its local file that is located in debug folder, but the main problem is system can get the full path of the txt file but cannot read the content since it says file cant be found. I tried everything to solve but i gues its a technical problem. Current OS windows11.

Comment: Dear MindSwipe, Error info:'C:\Users\Mehmet Faruk\OneDrive - sabanciuniv.edu\Belgeler\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\client\client\bin\Debug\database.txt' dosyası bulunamadı. This is the error message which is in Turkish but it says file could not be found.